# Adding users to Slack channel

Tags: c#, slack, slack-api

In the code I have, I am doing a POST request to a Slack API to create a channel for me. According to Slack's documentation, I could add users into "user_ids." Debugging wise I called another API called `channels.invite` and adding users is successful, so I don't know what's wrong with adding users through `conversations.create`

```
    class CreateChannels
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task CreateChannel()
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "token", "SLACK TOKEN" },
                { "name", "test" },
                { "is_private", "true" },
                { "user_ids", "USER-ID"}
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://slack.com/api/conversations.create", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        }
}


  [1]: https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create
```

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am able to create a channel through conversations.create but no users were added along with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work, because the parameter `user_ids` only works for so called workspace apps, but not for normal Slack like yours. You need to use `conversations.invite`.

From the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create) (emphasis mine):

> Required for workspace apps. A list of between 1 and 30 human users
>   that will be added to the newly-created conversation. T**his argument
>   has no effect when used by classic Slack apps**.